# Wav audio file compression not working

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, wav

Is it possible to compress a wav audio file without reducing the sampling rate?

I have an audio file with 256 bit rate and sampling rate - 8000Hz. I would just like to reduce the bit rate to 128/64 kbs

I tried converting to mp3 and back to wav,
   ffmpeg -i input.wav 1.mp3
   ffmpeg -i "1.mp3" -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 4000 out.wav
but this reduced sampling rate as well.
   ffmpeg -i "1.mp3" -acodec pcm_s16le -ab 128 out.wav  has default 256 bit rate

Answer (score 6):

### PCM (WAV) is uncompressed, so `-b:a`/`-ab` is ignored.

The bitrate of WAV is directly affected by the sample rate, channel layout, and bits per sample.

---

### Calculating PCM/WAV bitrate

Assuming 8000 samples per second, stereo channel layout, 16 bits per sample:

```
sample rate × number of channels × bits per sample = bitrate
8000 × 2 × 16 = 256000 bits/s, or 256 kb/s
```

### Getting channels, sample rate, bit depth

You can just view the output of `ffmpeg -i input.wav` or use `ffprobe` for a more concise output:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=sample_rate,channels,bits_per_sample -of default=nw=1 input.wav 
sample_rate=8000
channels=2
bits_per_sample=16
```

### Changing the bitrate

Bitrate should not be a consideration when using WAV. If bitrate is a problem then WAV is the wrong choice for you. That being said, you can change the bitrate by changing:

- The sample rate (`-ar`)
- The number of channels (`-ac`)
- The bit depth. For PCM/WAV the bit depth is the number listed in the encoder name: `-c:a pcm_s24le`, `-c:a pcm_s16le`, `-c:a pcm_u8`, etc. See `ffmpeg -encoders`.

Examples for 128 kb/s (this will probably sound bad):

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 8000 -ac 1 -c:a pcm_s16le output.wav
ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 8000 -ac 2 -c:a pcm_s8 output.wav
```

Another option is to use a lossless compressed format. The quality will be the same as WAV but the file size can be significantly smaller. Example for FLAC:

```
$ ffmpeg -i audio.wav audio.flac
$ ls -alh audio.wav audio.flac
  6.1M audio.flac
   11M audio.wac
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this using [Audacity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/)

1) import the wav file to audacity

2) Then File>Export

3) Choose "Constant" and then from the Quality drop-down select your required  bit-rate

I haven't tried that with ffmpeg, but the command should be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -ab 64000 output.wav
```

Comment: Thanks,,I will try it out. I have many files to process...is there a command line converter? or how can we handle multiple files at a time in audacity?

Comment: Yes, Audacity has a batch process option called Chain. Read the "Apply to Files" section of this page: http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Apply_Chain

Comment: try this: ffmpeg -i input.wav -b 64000 output.wav