# What role does bit rate play in the accuracy of Google Speech To Text transcription?

Tags: ffmpeg, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I am helping a client convert a video file using `ffmpeg` and they originally used `-b:a 64k` while transcoding their video to audio at a sampling rate (`-ar 44100` argument in `ffmpeg`) of 44100. Their objective is that they want to generate the most accurate transcriptions using the Google Cloud Speech To Text API.

While combing through their documentation I did not find anything on how bit rate impacts the accuracy of the transcription. So my question is thus - would using a higher bit rate such as `128k` help me in getting better transcriptions or does it not matter?

Comment: Did you try both bitrates and notice a difference in the speech-to-text output? Are you working with mono or stereo files? What is the audio format you are providing? 64k for mono voice for MP3 and AAC should be fine.

Comment: I tried higher bitrates but did not notice a difference in the STT outputs. I am working with mono files. The audio for is PCM Linear 16. Should I use ffmpeg to convert to a higher bit rate?

Comment: PCM has no bitrate parameter. The bitrate is fixed and depends on sample rate, bits per sample, and channel layout. See [Wav audio file compression not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522868/).

Answer (score 1):

Bitrate is used to describe the amount of data being transferred into audio. A higher bitrate generally means better audio quality. Higher bit rate contains more details in general sense, meaning it has better sound quality. Comparing it to photos, a high resolution picture is of better quality since in contains more details.

[Google reference](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices) suggests to capture an audio with a sampling rate of `16,000Hz` or higher for optimal results in using `Google Speech-to-Text`. Thus, a higher sampling rate or bit rate is preferred for optimal results since it is high quality.

If your are working on `mono` audio files, which is low quality in theory, and you converted it to a higher bit rate, this will not necessarily increase audio quality after its conversion. If the source audio file used to convert it to a higher bit rate, this will ideally yield to the same quality just increasing its bit rate. Thus, it is very important that you record your audio files using a higher bit rate in the first place.